# Set transparency/saturation of palette in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, alpha, palette

Let's start with the `viridis` palette. In my opinion, colours are a bit just too bright for me, and for my purposes they look too artificial. therefore, I would like to apply some sort of transparency or similar to reduce saturation:

```
library(nord)
library(scales)
library(viridis)
library(nord)

show_col(viridis(5))
show_col(viridis(5, alpha=.5))
```

Applying alpha transparency internally seems to work. 
[image].

However, when run in ggplot, it automatically changes alpha to 1 and plots the original viridis in full intensity:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(5, alpha=.5)
```

[image]

In another example, I found the opposite problem, lack of intensity/saturation. For example, the "aurora" palette from the `nord` package is great, but it looks a bit faded, lacking some saturation, at least for my purposes.

```
show_col(nord("aurora",5))
```

[image]

Similarly, I tried to set alpha internally, in this case to 1, but this pruduces a different effect as compared to viridis, changing the palette.

```
show_col(nord("aurora", alpha=.5))
```

[image]
Alternatively, I have set alpha as `alpha()`. However, this only changes the color names, but they look the same.

```
show_col(alpha(nord("aurora",5)), .5)
```

[image]

**How can I reduce saturation/intensity in `viridis`and increase in the `nord` palettes in `ggplot`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the viridis colors to reduce their saturation without making them transparent. I was hoping you could do this within the `viridis` function, but it doesn't look like there's a way to do that. Instead, the example below is a function that converts a vector of hexadecimal input colors (we'll create this vector with the `viridis` function) to the `hsv` colorspace, adjusts the `saturation` and `value` levels and then converts back to hexadecimal.

The approach below is a bit convoluted. There are probably more direct ways to transform between color systems.

```
vir_lite = function(cols, ds=0.4, dv=0.7) {
  cols = rgb2hsv(col2rgb(cols))
  cols["v", ] = cols["v", ] + dv*(1 - cols["v", ])
  cols["s", ] = ds*cols["s", ]
  apply(cols, 2, function(x) hsv(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
}
```

Here are the original `viridis` colors:

```
show_col(viridis(5))
```

[image]

And the adjusted colors:

```
show_col(vir_lite(viridis(5)))
```

[image]

You can change the adjusted colors by changing the `ds` and `dv` arguments. Now let's use the adjusted colors in the plot:

```
p = ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
      geom_raster(aes(fill = density))

p + scale_fill_gradientn(colors=vir_lite(viridis(5)))
```

[image]

```
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colors=vir_lite(viridis(5), ds=0.6, dv=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked to both decrease saturation in viridis and increase it in nord. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming `ds` is for desaturate, but what is the `dv` variable doing here?

Comment: Well, I wrote this answer 2.7 years ago, when I was smarter than I am now, but I think `dv` is the adjustment to the value dimension of the `hsv` color.

Answer (score 4):

Add your alpha value to the `geom_raster()` layer:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
    geom_raster(alpha = 0.5, aes(fill = density)) +
    scale_fill_viridis(5)
```

[image]

Comment: This works, the problem is that with my real data this applies alpha not only to the fill of geom_raster but also to the other "layers", background, border lines, etc, fading the entire plot

Comment: What's the call you're using with your real data? You may be able to reset the alpha in those layers to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You have a little typo in your last function. the `.5` is within `show_col` and not within `alpha`. So within `show_col` it gets interpret as a rounded `1` and this is boolean `TRUE` which leads to show the HEX values.

So the correct line would be

```
show_col(alpha(nord("aurora",5), .5))
```

And this produces the faint colors.

Comment: I just realised I didn't read the complete question :-D Just identified the wrong brackets.

Comment: Well I stopped with part 1, so between us we solved it :)

Comment: Thanks to both! The typo solves the technical aspect of including alpha with the "aurora" palette. However, setting alpha to 1 does not affect the palette. I had the feeling alpha in ´nord´ was set to <1 so adjusting to 1 could increase saturation. But no. So my question still remains: how can I increase saturation (make colours brighter) in the nord palette?

Comment: Just a comment on the HEX values which were changing using alpha. The normal HEX code has only 3 channels time 2 digits like `#FF3355`, by using alpha, you add a 4th channel to it which is for example `FF` for no transparency and `80` for 50% transparency.